# Finding GPS coordinates of point located between 2 known meridians?

Tags: distance, gps, wgs84

I need to solve this task. How to find GPS coordinates of a point which is 1029.96033 km from prime meridian and 747.67936 km from 25th meridian, using WGS84 standard.

It is a particular task but I am also interested in the general solution.

Can you help?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about our focussed Q&A format. For your question to be answered here it should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: Were you not given any more information? There is a limiting factor but once you find that, I think there are multiple possible answers.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt know. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very specific problem, but I found it pretty intriguing and interesting, so here is my general approach for this problem, as well as my answer.

I assumed that your 25th meridian was in the Eastern Hemisphere.

There are actually 2 symmetric solutions to the problem, one in the Northern, and one in the Southern hemisphere. Let's solve for the Northern hemisphere.

When we calculate (shortest) distances from a point to a line, the segment representing that distance intersects the line at a 90° angle. Based on that principle, let's start at 0° latitude on the prime meridian, and move 1029.96033 km starting with a bearing of 90° (Due East). Then, from that endpoint, we calculate the remaining (shortest) distance to reach the 25th meridian (with a final bearing of 90°), and get a distance of 1753.02694 km. This is much more than the stated distance of 747.67936 km, so we have to try a different latitude, and reevaluate this remaining distance after the same process. With a few trials, using an iterative method, we find the desired geometric configuration which matches that last distance. The iterative method that I used was a basic linear estimation, and it converged pretty fast. The formulas that I used to calculate distances and bearings on an ellipsoid are described in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae). Some online tools and GIS software have already implemented those formulas and can be used for calculations.

And now, the solution : the point you're looking for is located at 50.1528165° N, 14.5035333 E, near the Cakovice Hypermarket in Prague.

Comment: Thank you for your extensive and helpful reply.
I will try to do it on my own too :)